# CssSandpaper library error - rules object empty

Tags: javascript

I've got a problem with [CssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/) script. Once I run it on one of my site's pages, I get following error:

```
"rules is null" in FF,
"Error: 'rules.length' is null or not an object" in IE,
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" in Chrome,
```

so basically object 'rules' is undefined. Here is CSS for my div (id="textTransform"):

```
#textTransform {
border: 1px solid green;
-sand-transform: rotate(90deg);
width: 23px;
height: 74px;
```

}

Has anyone of you ever had such issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've got it. This library gets all the references that are listed in "link" tags in you "meta" section in HTML. I've had this line that defines a link to favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

The favicon wasn't present at the server and its response was 404. That was the reason. Once I removed it it start working.

Answer (score 1):

Two things for me caused an "uncaught exception error" in combination with the csssandpaper.js and the other required scripts for the css sandpaper library.

1. html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet
2. Typekit js

Removing both of those removed the error